# Addin for drawing lines between nested blocks in the Visual Studio IDE code editor

Tags: ide, visual-studio-2008

When using Resharper or CodeRush Express in the Visual Studio 2008 IDE, these tools modify the code editor with additional effects, such as the drawing of lines between the start and end of code blocks, if statements, switch statements etc.

Does anyone know if there is a Visual Studio addin that can do this without the bloat and overhead of the full products? I currently have CodeRush Express installed on my personal machine but I don't use any of it's functionality and so I want to uninstall it. But I do like those lines!

Hopefully this question makes at least some semblance of sense to people!

Thanks;
Richard Moss

Comment: Well technically you do use some of it's functionality - the lines ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "[Indent Guides](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e792686d-542b-474a-8c55-630980e72c30)" extension on the Visual Studio gallery does this. Tested in C#, JavaScript and Razor views so far and it works nicely.